# Как передать данные с одного UserControl в другой

Tags: c#, winforms, visual-studio-2017, usercontrol

У меня есть два User Control: ProgramsUS и ее дочерняя ShowCodeUS. На ProgramsUS находится treeview, нажимая на его узел, появляется ShowCodeUS. Проблема в том, что  одновременно при нажатии на узел treeviw в textboxCode, который находится в ShowCodeUS, должен вводиться текст. Не понимаю, как реализовать передачу данных между UserControl.

```
      private void treeView1_AfterSelect(object sender, TreeViewEventArgs e)
    {
        showCode1.BringToFront();
        //передать текст в textboxCode 

    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Решение "в лоб".

У ShowCodeUS сделать метод, который будет принимать нужный текст и в обработчике событий вызывать этот метод. Например:

```
showCode1.BringToFront();
showCode1.SetText("My Text");
```

Внутри метода `SetText` выводите текст куда нужно.

А, вообще по хорошему нужно использовать паттерны (MVVM или MVP). Это сильно упростит работу.

Comment: а если мне нужно передать содержимое текстового файла?

Comment: Можно перегнать его в String или использовать соответствующий объект. А, вообще по хорошему нужно использовать паттерны (MVVM или MVP). Это сильно упростит работу.

Answer (score 1):

Если проект не совсем большой, и не придётся много переписывать, то вариант, переехать на MVVM, и просто в ViewModel записывать состояние из TreeView,  а в нужном UserControl, цеплять это состояние.